# Conditional problem system (How do I convert my intuitive grasp of this concept into math?)

Tags: probability

NOTE: This is a practice exam question for a upcoming midterm.

Consider a system with four components arranged as shown. The system works if there is a path from the left side to the right side passing only through working components. Assume the components work independently of each other and that each works with probability .8.

[image]

(a) What is the probability that the system works?

￼￼￼(b) What is the probability that the system works, given that component A fails?

(c) Given that the system failed, what is the probability that component A failed?

---

I am having quite a mind knot with this. I feel like I understand it intuitively, but I'm having a hard time using the conditional probability formula.

PART A)

The probability that the system works is: $$P( (A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D) ) = .8^2 + .8^2 - .8^4 = .8704$$

PART B)

This is 
$$P( (A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D) | A^c ) = \frac{P( ((A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)) \cap A^c )}{P(A^c)},$$
right? See, intuitively I know that if $A$ fails, there is only one branch for the system the succeed, which is $(C \cap D)$, so the probability of the system succeeding despite $A$ failing would be $.8^2 = .64$ right? However, in the original formula, isn't $$\frac{P( [(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)] \cap A^c )}{P(A^c)} = .64 / .2 \text{ ...?}$$
But that equals 3.2

How do I convert my intuitive grasp of this concept into math?

PART C)

$P( A^c | ((A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D))^c )$, stuck...

UPDATE: Alright I think I may have it:

$$P( [(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)] \cap A^c )$$

= $$P( [A^c \cap (A \cap B)] \cup [A^c \cap (C \cap D)] )$$

= $$P( [\emptyset] \cup [A^c \cap (C \cap D)] )$$

= $$P( [A^c \cap (C \cap D)] )$$ = .2*.8*.8 = .2 * .64, then we would divide by .2 to get .64! Right? Maybe? Is that how it goes?

UPDATE 2: So now for Part C)

$$P( A^c | [(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)]^c) = \frac{P( A^c \cap [(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)]^c)}{P([(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)]^c)}$$

= $$\frac{P( A^c \cap [(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)]^c)}{1 - P([(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)])}$$

= $$\frac{P( A^c \cap [(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)]^c)}{1 - .8704}$$

= $$\frac{P( A^c \cap [(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)]^c)}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{P( A^c \cap [(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)]^c)}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{P( A^c \cap [(A \cap B)^c \cap (C \cap D)^c])}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{P( A^c \cap [(A^c \cup B^c) \cap (C^c \cup D^c)])}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{P([A^c \cap (A^c \cup B^c)] \cap (C^c \cup D^c))}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{P( A^c \cap (C^c \cup D^c))}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{P( [A^c \cap C^c] \cup [A^c \cap D^c))}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{.2*.2 + .2*.2 - (.2*.2)*(.2*.2)}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{2*.2^2 - .2^4}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{2*.2^2 - .2^4}{.1296}$$

= $$\frac{.0784}{.1296}$$

= $$.604938???$$ Whaaaa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For B, I don't know where you get $.64/.2$. The numerator is $P(C\cap D\cap A^c)$ which is $(.8)(.8)(.2)$, and the denominator is $.2$, so the answer is $.64$, as you obtained by other means.

EDIT: For C, let's write $S$ for system works (so $S^c$ for system fails). You want $P(A^c|S^c)$. We have $$P(A^c|S^c)={P(A^c\cap S^c)\over P(S^c)}={P(S^c|A^c)P(A^c)\over P(S^c)}$$ Now you worked out $P(S)$ already, so you know the denominator, and you worked out $P(S|A^c)$ already, so you know both terms in the numerator.

Comment: For sure, I feel pretty good about B now, Still stuck on C. I just got .1296 / .1296 which is boggling my mind.

Comment: Alright, I'm with you up to the point when you say I have worked out $$P(S|A^c)$$ and so I know all the terms in the numerator, but the numerator has the term: $$P(S^c|A^c)$$, is there an easy way to convert between $$P(S|A^c)$$ and $$P(S^c|A^c)$$?

Comment: Yes, there is, and if I tell you what it is, you'll slap yourself on the forehead.

Comment: I must know! Lets see, they're both divided by $$A^c$$, maybe it's one minus $$P(S^c)$$ ... dang! How? The not knowing is killing me! (keeps looking at it)

Comment: Theorem: For all $X$, $Y$, $P(X|Y)+P(X^c|Y)=1$.

Comment: Ah man, of course!